# What is the font used in the logo and product names of Robotis Inc.?

Tags: font-identification

[Robotis Inc.](http://robotis.com/) uses this font in the logo.

[image: Logo of Robotis Inc.]

It's also used in their product names, as you can see on their webseite. Here are a few examples.

[image: Robotis Dynamixel Pro]

[image: Robotis Darwin-Mini]

I manually moved the letters apart a bit, so that WhatTheFont can detect them, but it does not list very similar fonts. What font is this?

Comment: We have a collection of font identification resources [right here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info), and it is a good idea to try those first. Please let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increase. Thanks!

Comment: ...and please keep the possibility in mind that this is a custom-designed typeface.

Comment: @Vincent Thanks for the link, I'll try the services and tell you if I could come up with something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Identifont did the trick. It looks like Robotis Inc. built on Viper Squadron Solid, but added angle cuts to some letters.

[image: Viper Squadron]